# Is it possible to run a public facing server, if my ISP proxies connections?

Tags: proxy, isp

I have satelite broadband in my house (it's the only ISP I can get).

A rough network diagram is below

```
The internet
      |
My ISP
      |
My IP address (what every site sees) 84.x.x.x. At least 3 customers of my
ISP are behind this IP address. Also is gateway.myisp.com
      |
The box in my house (part router, part satelite signal decrypter,
part satelite dish power supply) 192.x.x.1
      |
My router 10.0.0.1 (Also 192.x.x.100 )
      |
My PC 10.0.0.5
```

I'm not able to change the settings on my ISP's box. Within my house, 84.x.x.x is a page for mikrotik routeros (nothing I can change), 192.x.x.x is a password prompt, 10.0.0.1 is my router, and 10.0.0.5 is apache on my pc.

Outside, 84.x.x.x is a blank white page and 192.x.x.x is server not found.

My IP is not dynamic, I've had the same one for over a year now. Going onto speedtest shows several hundred results for 84.x.x.x, with varying speeds that definitely aren't my connection, some at the same time as I've been online.

I know I've phrased this question horribly, but this really isn't my area, any help to put it better from anyone would be appreciated.

What I want to know is, given that my ISP is probably proxying my connections, and my public-facing IP is probably shared, is it at all possible for me to run a internet accessible server of any kind (apache, irc, games, etc.)?

(Another oddity that may be related: IRC servers, and bittorrent clients that usually get a IP address instead get a hostname which is just gateway.myisp.com )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not possible without talking to your ISP and convincing him to forward you at least one port. Then you'd have to configure all your routers to forward that port to your machine. After that your server would be accessible from outside with: your.isp.com:forwarded_port/

The other way is tunneling but you need a friend with public server who would set up a VPN for you ALSO with some port forwarding. Then your machine would be accessible with: your.friends.net:forwarded_port/